# Getting zero-values from a right joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, outer-join

This is the structure of tables in my database:

```
**Email**
id (PK)
email

**Mail**
id (PK)
recipient
time
...
```

In order to get the distribution of mails received by specific emails, I do this query:

```
select e.email,count(m.id) from mail m 
    right outer join email e on m.recipient=e.email
    group by e.email
```

I get:

```
"e1";0
"e2";3644
"e3";0
"e4";10
"e5";4620
..
```

All values from table Email are matched, that is all emails and those with `count=0`. This is ok.

The problem is when I filter the results by date:

```
select e.email,count(m.id) from mail m 
right outer join email e on m.recipient=e.email
where m.time >= current_timestamp - interval '1 hour'
group by e.email
```

The result is:

```
"e1";1
"e2";1
"e3";1
...
```

I don' t get the values that have `count=0`, I just get the emails that have rows in table Mail.
What am I  doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filter by messages that arrived in the last hour, you'll only get people who have one of those messages.

Check for null too.

```
WHERE m.time IS NULL OR m.time > current_timstamp...
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep unmatched rows from the *main* table in the loop when dealing with [`OUTER` joins (`LEFT` is just the inverse of `RIGHT`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN), you need to put respective conditions into the **`JOIN` clause** instead of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT e.email, count(m.id)
FROM   email e
LEFT   JOIN mail m ON m.recipient = e.email
                  AND m.time >= now() - interval '1 hour'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This way, rows from `mail` are only appended if they match the join conditions - else the appended columns default to `NULL` (but the row is still returned).

If you put conditions in the `WHERE` clause, the *result* has to match (*after* joining tables) - else the whole row is discarded from the output.

You *can* catch the problem by adding `OR col IS NULL` or to every respective condition in the `WHERE` clause, but that's generally slower and less elegant.

#### Asides

Don't use `time` as column name. It's allowed in Postgres, but it's a base type name and a reserved word in the SQL standard. Can lead to confusing errors and error messages.

`count(m.recipient)` might be a bit safer/faster than `count(m.id)`. If `mail.id` should not be defined `NOT NULL`, it could lead to unexpected results. `mail.recipient` cannot be `NULL` for matched rows by definition in this query.